# Filemaker XSL 20sec Query Latency

Tags: xslt, asp-classic, filemaker

I have an ASP frontend that loads data from a Filemaker database using XSL to perform simple queries. The problem is that the first page load takes 20 seconds +/- 200ms, then the next few page refreshes within a minute of the first request take <200ms, then the cycle starts over again.

Each page load makes only 2 XSL queries, and they execute fast after the first page load, so **what is causing the delay on the first page load?** I have caching turned up with a 100% hit rate, and number of connections at 100. I've tried with XSL database sessions on and off, and session time anywhere from 1 to 60 minutes without any changes.

The XSL loads from ASP use a GET request and add a Basic `Authorization` header to authenticate each time.

During fast page requests, the `fmserver.exe` and `fmswpc.exe` processes don't even flinch, but during a 20 second holdup I see `fmserver` jump to 30% CPU and a 3mb I/O read a few seconds into the request, and occasionally `fmswpc` jump to 60% CPU.

Comment: I think that for performance you need a precompiled transformation running like a service instead of parsing the stylesheet every time (I don't think cache mechanism have something to improve here)

Comment: The problem isn't the parsing time of the stylesheet, as some page loads run in acceptable time (200ms). The problem is some latency in creating the stylesheet in the first place (ie: when I try and load the stylesheet URL to view the returned XML I still get a 20sec delay).

Comment: Maybe there is some kind of optimization on the ASP framework and it's doing what I wrote: preserving the compiled stylesheet in memory for you to reuse. Of course, that automatic optimization can't goes on forever because of memory leaks optimizations. There should be a way for declaring this explicity.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that the cache you're referring to is the FileMaker XSLT cache (i.e. you switched from what it calls 'development mode' to 'production mode' and enabled stylesheet caching)?

Comment: @Mikhail: yes, it is switched to 'production mode' with stylesheet caching turned on. @Alejandro: I don't see how ASP could be caching the request as it creates a new `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP`, sends a `GET` request, then interprets the result as XML. Filemaker also seems to stuck processing requests one at a time, as parallel requests during a 20sec freeze also freeze and then complete all at the same time. There's also some fishy process stats going on, see above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, for some reason it was the `Authorization` header that caused the lag. If I gave the guest account full access and removed that header, every request was fast. Go figure.

Comment: When you were accessing it with the authorized account (not guest), did that privilege set have a custom calculation to restrict record level privileges? This can potentially cause speed issues.

Comment: No, it was using a standard account with read-write privileges. The problem might also have been that the rows returned were referencing fields from an external file that also needed authentication, but the authentication used wasn't being passed on.

Answer (score 1):

If you're accessing the FileMaker server on the same machine, be sure to use '127.0.0.1' instead of 'localhost'.